# How to remove/hide all Google Analytics data associated with a specific page?

Tags: google-analytics

For about a week, Google Analytics was erroneously reporting page views for a few request URIs, severely skewing my data. I have read that there is no way to remove data once it is reported. If this is the case, is there a way to simply hide this data from the view?

I have tried a number of things (such as creating global filters, view filters, etc.) to no avail. Using segments also doesn't work, because apparently you can only filter out visits/users (whereas my goal is to filter out page views associated with a specific page). At this point, I feel like I must be going about it the totally wrong way...

Below is a screenshot of the **Behavior > Overview** section. The page views I want to move are #1, #2, and #5.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alex**, unfortunately, there is nothing you can do about the historical data.

However, you can use simple filter to exclude pages you don't want to see (the filter field above the report table, not filters related to account/profiles) -- see the attached screen below.

[image]

Make sure you select *exclude* and then pick *Page* dimension. The easiest way would be to use regular expressions, like:

```
(a|b|c)
```

This one would remove any pages that contain either "a", or "b" or "c".

**The expression would be probably a bit more complicated in your case and I suggest using tools like [RegEx Hero](http://regexhero.net/) (free, online). I am not sure if there is anything common for the pages you would like to remove from the reports, but regular expression can do quite a lot :).**

One last thing -- be aware there is a slight difference in segments and (table) filters. If you use segments for page dimension, you would end up with ALL the pages that were seen during a visit, which includes the page you set in the segment. Might be a bit confusing, but see [this article](http://www.analyticscanvas.com/segments-vs-filters-in-google-analytics/) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! (BTW, the article you linked to appears to be dead... or at least no HTML is loading for me).

Comment: Alex, try this link of Google chached version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GrvZLfiHSGQJ:www.analyticscanvas.com/segments-vs-filters-in-google-analytics